# Fill a combo box by selecting item in ListView

Tags: c#, listview, selectedindexchanged

Im trying to fill `combobox` from one of  two `arraylist`,  on changing selection in `listview`  with method `listView1_SelectedIndexChanged`.
The problem is it works fine the first time, but the second time I get the following error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

The error is probably happening here: `string pr = listView1.FocusedItem.Text;`

Please help.

```
    private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ArrayList Profesor1 = new ArrayList();
        Profesor1.Add("Kolegij 1 profesor 1");
        Profesor1.Add("Kolegij 2 profesor 1");



        ArrayList Profesor2 = new ArrayList();
        Profesor2.Add("Kolegij 1 profesor 2");
        Profesor2.Add("Kolegij 2 profesor 2");



        string pr = listView1.FocusedItem.Text; //posible prob
        switch (pr)
        {
            case "Profesor 1": comboBox1.DataSource = Profesor1;
                break;
            case "Profesor 2": comboBox1.DataSource = Profesor2;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there something else going on in your example affecting the `listView1` item? I've mocked up a small clone of your question and I can't seem to replicate the error:

I'm using your code for the event handler, and I'm populating the `listView1` thusly:

```
        listView1.Items.Add("Profesor 1");
        listView1.Items.Add("Profesor 2");
```

It sounds like you're causing the `listView1_SelectedIndexChanged` handler to be fired in the background.

As a slight aside, your array lists aren't going to change, you probably don't want to keep your ArrayList creation in your event handler and keep recreating them each time (they don't seem to have any dynamic information in). particularly as that handler will often be called twice once, for the deselection, and again for a selection.

On that last point, it's also worth having a look at the `ItemSelectionChanged` event, which could be used to help your initial problem, as it comes with `ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs`  which contain the property `IsSelected`, which you could use to verify that you have an object selected.

e.g:

```
private void listView1_ItemSelectionChanged(object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.IsSelected)
        {
            // Your code here.
            // e.Item...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thx for `private void listView1_ItemSelectionChanged(object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.IsSelected)
        {
            // Your code here.
        }
    }` this works fine..

Comment: I added  if statement (  **if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)** )  and works also fine. My code:            `if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
                {
                    string pr = listView1.FocusedItem.Text;
                    switch (pr)
                    {
                        case "Profesor 1": comboBox1.DataSource = kolegijiProfesor1;
                            break;
                        case "Profesor 2": comboBox1.DataSource = kolegijiProfesor2;
                            break;
                    }
                }`

Comment: Good stuff, I didn't manage to replicate the error, but glad you've fixed your problem =D

Comment: Thanks again m8. Your "listView1_ItemSelectionChanged" is better for this than "listView1_SelectedIndexChanged" + if statement "if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)". Tanks and may the Force be with You

Comment: Magic, also worth noting that `e.Item` will should contain the item you're interested in.